# Getting Enum Object from its value in Java. In Efficient way and Not using Map

Tags: java, enums

In `Enum` class, how to get the name of the `Enum` object using one of its  field values.

```
public enum Example {
    Object1("val1", "val2"),
    Object2("val3", "val4");
}
```

I have the `val1` with me. Can I get `Object1` using it ?

Comment: You'll need to create a static method named something like `getByVal1()` that compares to the possible values and returns when it matches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in following way with `O(1)` complexity if you can assure that every `Enum` constant will have unique first value. We have to create inner class to manage map of `val1` and `Example` because `Enum` will not allow us to add value in static map inside the *constructor*.

```
public enum Example {
    Object1("val1", "val2"), Object2("val3", "val4");

    private static final class ExampleValManager {
        static final Map<String, Example> EXAMPLE_VAL_MANAGER_MAP = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private String val1;

    private String val2;

    private Example(String val1, String val2) {
        this.val1 = val1;
        this.val2 = val2;
        ExampleValManager.EXAMPLE_VAL_MANAGER_MAP.put(val1, this);
    }

    public static Example getExampleByVal1(String val) {
        return ExampleValManager.EXAMPLE_VAL_MANAGER_MAP.get(val);
    }
}
```

Use it in following way,

```
public class Test {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(Example.getExampleByVal1("val1"));
   }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Object1
```

Comment: It's O(1) best-case, but if there are only a few enum values, the cost of the lookup will dwarf a simple array traversal.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually show anything that those strings correspond to, so I'll assume you have fields named `foo` and `bar`:

```
public enum Example {
    final String foo;
    final String bar;

    private Example(String foo, String bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

In order to look up by `foo`, you'll just need some method that looks for a match:

```
public static Example ofFoo(String foo) {
    for(Example e : Example.values()) {
        if(e.foo.equals(foo))
            return e;
    }

    return null;
}
```

As long as you don't have a crazy number of enum values, this will generally be fine. If performance is actually an issue, you can cache `Example.values()` in a private static array or even set up something like a Guava `ImmutableMap<String,Example>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `enum` would look as follows:

```
public enum Example {
    Object1("val1", "val2"),
    Object2("val3", "val4");

    String str1;
    String str2;

    Example(String str1, String str2){
        this.str1 = str1;
        this.str2 = str2;
    }

    static Example getEnumByStr1(String str1){
        for (Example e : values())
            if (e.str1.equals(str1))
                return e;
        return null;
    }
}
```

You can get the enum by string value then like that:

```
Example.getNameByStr1("val1");
```